# Python code reading serial inputs on Beaglebone

Tags: python, uart, beagleboard

I am trying to read the data from my Geiger Counter on my Beaglebone, but when I print the result, doesn't include my counter code:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.UART as UART
import serial
import time
UART.setup("UART4")

ser = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyO4", baudrate=9600)

r = 0
d = 0
z = 0
minutes = 0
while True:
    timeout = time.time() + 60
    while True:
            x = ser.read()
            if ser.isOpen():
                    print "Serial is open!"
                    r = r +1
                    print r
                    print x

            elif x is '0':
                d=d+1
                #print '.'
            elif x is '1':
                d=d+1
                #print '.'

    time.sleep(1)
    z=z+d
    print "CPM %f " % d
    print "total %f" % z
    print "minutes %f" % minutes
```

My output came out as:

```
Serial is open!

1

1

Serial is open!

2

1

Serial is open!

3

0
```

Comment: Not sure of your question, but the inner loop will never terminate (unless an exception occurs).

Comment: Cleaned up formatting/grammar/tags.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `break` in your inner `while` loop, so it will loop infinitely. Assuming counter code means the `print` statements at the end of your code sample, they will never be reached.